# std::experimental::source_location at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time, c++-experimental, std-source-location

`std::experimental::source_location` will probably be added to the C++ standard at some point. I'm wondering if it possible to get the location information into the compile-time realm. Essentially, I want a function that returns different types when called from different source locations. Something like this, although it doesn't compile because the `location` object isn't `constexpr` as it's a function argument:

```
#include <experimental/source_location>

using namespace std::experimental;

constexpr auto line (const source_location& location = source_location::current())
{
  return std::integral_constant<int, location.line()>{};
}

int main()
{
  constexpr auto ll = line();
  std::cout << ll.value << '\n';
}
```

This doesn't compile, with a message about

```
expansion of [...] is not a constant expression
```

regarding the `return std::integral_constant<int, location.line()>{}` line. What good it is to have the methods of `source_location` be `constexpr` if I can't use them?

Comment: This doesn't have to do with `std::experimental::source_location` at all. The `line` function is `constexpr`, but its arguments are not `constexpr`. Function arguments are never `constexpr`. In C++20, we may have arbitrary types as template arguments, so it's possible the `source_location` could be a template parameter

Comment: On further investigation, this is actually an interesting problem. The only way to get the late construction of the `source_location` object is with a defaulted function argument. A defaulted template argument wouldn't work; it's created early, not late. This may be an oversight. `constexpr` function arguments would fix the problem, but that idea isn't seen too favorably at this time

Answer (score 8):

As Justin pointed the issue with your code is that function argument are not constexpr but the problem of using source_location in a constexpr function in a more useful way is mentioned in the [constexpr! functions](https://wg21.link/p1073) proposal which says:

> The "Library Fundamentals v. 2" TS contains a "magic" source_location
>   class get to information similar to the **FILE** and **LINE** macros
>   and the **func** variable (see N4529 for the current draft, and N4129
>   for some design notes). Unfortunately, because the "value" of a
>   source_location is frozen at the point source_location::current() is
>   invoked, composing code making use of this magic class is tricky:
>   Typically, a function wanting to track its point of invocation has to
>   add a defaulted parameter as follows:
>
> ```
> void my_log_function(char const *msg,
>                      source_location src_loc
>                         = source_location::current()) {
>   // ...
> }
> ```
>
> This idiom ensure that the value of the source_location::current()
>   invocation is sampled where my_log_function is called instead of where
>   it is defined.
>
> Immediate (i.e., constexpr!) functions, however, create a clean
>   separation between the compilation process and the constexpr
>   evaluation process (see also P0992). Thus, we can make
>   source_location::current() an immediate function, and wrap it as
>   needed in other immediate functions: The value produced will
>   correspond to the source location of the "root" immediate function
>   call. For example:
>
> ```
> constexpr! src_line() {
>   return source_location::current().line();
> }
>
> void some_code() {
>   std::cout << src_line() << '\n';  // This line number is output.
> }
> ```

So this is currently an open problem.